# PDO Error With Function to Select

Tags: php, pdo

```
 function getColumn($sql, $params)
{
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    return $stmt->fetchColumn();
}


echo $db->getColumn("SELECT token FROM Sessions WHERE uid = ?", array(1));
```

I have created a function to help me load SQL queries. However, I get an error everytime:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::getColumn() in C:\wamp\www\firsttest\index.php on line 15
```

Why is PDO unable to recognize my getColumn function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function doesn't belong to the PDO class, so you don't call it from the pdo object.

So don't do this:

```
$db->getColumn("SELECT token FROM Sessions WHERE uid = ?", array(1));
```

Just call it:

```
getColumn("SELECT token FROM Sessions WHERE uid = ?", array(1));
```

or, since it looks like your function belongs to a class, do:

```
$yourClass->getColumn("SELECT token FROM Sessions WHERE uid = ?", array(1));
```

Comment: Yes, but then I get this error: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\wamp\www\firsttest\index.php on line 9

Comment: why are you using `$this` ?

Comment: how are you creating your `db` object?  If it's not part of a class, maybe you can do `$GLOBALS['db']->prepare($sql)`